# How to edit column(s) inplace in OpenRefine?

Tags: openrefine

I am trying to apply regex to a column in OpenRefine. In fact, I have a lot of regexes that I don't want to combine. ('cuz I want to see the results each time I apply them.) I can apply them by following `Edit column> Add column based on this column...` . But doing this way results in many unwanted columns. My question is: how can I edit a column inplace? I mean without creating a new column and editing the existing column. Is this possible? (**This is not regex specific question. I am asking editing a column in general.**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `Edit column`, use `Edit cells` → `Transform`.